# Does Inactive Oracle Sessions may lead to high CPU usage or increase CPU wait time?

Tags: oracle, cpu

If I am having quite a number of Inactive DB Sessions which also might be used in CONNECTION POOL I want to know whether they may lead to any high CPU utilization or increase the CPU wait Cycles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple words, an `INACTIVE` status in `v$session` means no SQL statement is being executed at the time you check in `v$session`.

By nature, a high number of `ACTIVE` sessions will slow down the whole DBMS including your application and may lead to high CPU utilization.

Inactive sessions will have a low impact unless you exceed the maximum session number.

**CPU Usage for Active Sessions** can be checked by the below query.

```
SELECT
   s.username,
   t.sid,
   s.serial#,
   SUM(VALUE/100) as "cpu usage (seconds)"
FROM
   v$session s,
   v$sesstat t,
   v$statname n
WHERE
   t.STATISTIC# = n.STATISTIC#
AND
   NAME like '%CPU used by this session%'
AND
   t.SID = s.SID
AND
   s.status='ACTIVE'
AND
   s.username is not null
GROUP BY username,t.sid,s.serial#
/
```

Check out the ORACLE v$session documentation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2088.htm#REFRN30223

Comment: Thanks @XING for your answer . Could you please specify one more thing whether it has impact on Application Performance ? I mean CPU is ok but whether Application will behave normal or may become bit slow .

Comment: I already mentioned, it hardly impacts you application until  you exceed the maximum session number.